# Cloning anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Hello I've used this patter to get a static variable

```
 var uniqueID = (function() {
 var id = 0; // This is the private persistent value
 // The outer function returns a nested function that has access
 // to the persistent value.  It is this nested function we're storing
 // in the variable uniqueID above.
 return function() { return id++; };  // Return and increment
 })(); // Invoke the outer function after defining it.
```

Now I'm trying to clone this function, but backup and the original still return sequential  values. How can i "freeze" the status of the function when copy it?

Thanks

Comment: How are you copying it?

Comment: Just var backUp=uniqueID...actually i've no idea

Comment: Since you have no idea how to clone it, why do you think you should clone it? Do you want two functions that each generate unique sequences?

Comment: Isn't it always going to be 1 or undefined?

Comment: I need to store the status of the function at some time, use it, and then restore the status. Let's say uniqueId() returns 0, then i copy it backUp=uniqueID, then uniqueId() returns 1, now if i call backup() it returns 2 instead of 1..,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, something like this extremely convoluted contraption should work (fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dPLj6/):

```
var uniqueIdFunction = function(initialValue) {
    var id = initialValue || 0; 
    var result = function() { return id++; };
    result.clone = function(){ return uniqueIdFunction(id); }
    return result;  
}; 

var uniqueId1 = uniqueIdFunction();
```

Use the clone method to get a clone. The original will keep it's own internal id value. The clone will take its initial internal id from the clone source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that generates unique id generators:

```
var createGenerator = function(id) {
  var id = id || 0;
  return function() { return id++; }; 
}

var g1 = createGenerator();
var g2 = createGenerator();

console.log(g1(), g1(), g1());
console.log(g2(), g2());
console.log(g1());
console.log(g2());

// OP's cloning scenario
var freezeId = g1();
var clone = createGeenrator(freezeId);
console.log(g1(),g1());
console.log(clone());
```

@pax162's answer is more in line with what the OP wants to do. I just decided to post the more normal way of doing it.